# Principled way to find a shape with symmetries given by a group

Tags: group-theory, geometry, dihedral-groups

Recently I've learned how groups correspond to symmetries of objects so I've been trying to find shapes corresponding to groups that I know (all with finite groups).

For example, I know $\mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z$ for $p$ prime is cyclic so it makes sense to try a prime-sided regular polygon because it has no reflectional symmetries, so there's nothing to do except rotate it by one turn until you've done $p$ rotations and are back where you started. But for non-cyclic groups I don't know in general how to proceed.

My problem is that so far I've basically been guessing and checking. Like I figured out a shape that has $K_4$ as its symmetries, but I wasn't actually looking to find $K_4$, I was trying to find a different group. How can I do a better job of producing a shape that I want?

An example: $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$. I can't think of what to use. An isosceles triangle seems to correspond to $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ since the only symmetry is reflection along the line bisecting the non-congruent angle. So I tried gluing two isosceles triangles together along the non-congruent side, but that's how I ended up with $K_4$. And the other shapes I've tried, like a square or 6 pointed star, all have too much symmetry.

Is there even a single shape giving $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$? Is this a general thing for $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ when $n$ is not prime? I know this is connected to the dihedral group -- what does that mean for my endeavor? Am I only able to find such a shape if the group in question is a dihedral group?

Sorry if this has been asked before, I searched and didn't see it but clearly I'm pretty new to group theory so i might have not recognized a solution when I saw it. Thanks for any help.

---

As an example of the kinds of shapes I want, I basically want polygons.

This is $K_4$ taken from [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group) on it. I'm very happy with this shape.
[image: K_4]

For $\mathbb Z / 5 \mathbb Z$, there's the regular pentagon. That works great for me.

That sort of shape. I have been thinking very much in terms of "classical" shapes although I'd definitely be interested in broadening my "shape" horizons if that's insightful.

Comment: Wait, why do prime-sided regular polygons have no reflectional symmetries?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "shape"? An arbitrary mathematical object? A subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$? A simplicial complex?

Comment: @Nate i've updated with an actual shape

Comment: @angryavian maybe i'm confused, is it more that the rotations of a $p$-sided regular pentagon give $\mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z$ but there are more symmetries, we just choose to ignore them for that group? Upon further thought, i see with an equilateral triangle there are only rotations unless we allow the indices to get mixed up too. Is that correct?

Comment: @alfalfa If you choose to ignore the reflectional symmetries, then the rotations of any $n$-sided regular polygon form $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. For each $n$, this is a subgroup of the full group of symmetries (rotations and reflections) of the $n$-sided regular polygon, called the [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group).

Comment: @angryavian thank you for the info -- if i was to have an actual physical pentagon with the top and bottom different, am i correct in that the only symmetries would necessarily be from rotations alone? But if the top and bottom are the same then it could be flipped over to get more symmetries?

Comment: @alfalfa Oh I see what you mean now. Then yes, I suppose that works. (But again, there is nothing special about $n$ being prime here.)

Comment: FYI: The idea of interpreting group elements as geometric isometries is part of ["representation theory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory).

Comment: @Blue thanks, i didn't know about that, that is very helpful